# I am unable to watermark a GIF file with alpha in php. Is it possible to show transparent string in GIF file?

Tags: php, image, gif, watermark

I have problem in writing a transparent watermark in a Gif Image in php. It writes but do not show the transparency. I have an image that have a table with information i have to water mark in that file so that data shown on file should not be disturb. Means, watermark should be transparent and viewable.
Please help me. Code is something like this.

```
                    $imagesource="pics/2011/temp/15_03.gif";
                    $DestinationFile="pics/2011/15_03.gif";
        $filetype = substr($imagesource,strlen($imagesource)-4,4); 
        $filetype = strtolower($filetype); 
        if($filetype == ".gif")  $image = @imagecreatefromgif($imagesource);  
        if($filetype == ".jpg")  $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imagesource);  
        if($filetype == ".png")  $image = @imagecreatefrompng($imagesource);  
        if (!$image) die();         
        $imagewidth = imagesx($image); 
        $imageheight = imagesy($image);         
        $startwidth = (($imagewidth *20)/100); 
        $startheight = $imageheight - ($imageheight*20)/100;
        //imagecopy($image, $watermark,  $startwidth, $startheight, 0, 0, $watermarkwidth, $watermarkheight); 
        $color   = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 111, 0,75);
        imagettftext($image,24,60,$startwidth,$startheight,$color,'arial.ttf',"(c)www.Example.com");
        imagejpeg($image,$DestinationFile,85);
        imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: GIF doesn't support alpha transparency.

Comment: How can something be both transparent and viewable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should create the watermark on another image and use the merge function:

```
$watermark = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$color   = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 111, 0);
imagettftext($watermark ,24,60,$startwidth,$startheight,$color,'arial.ttf',"(c)www.Example.com");
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');

imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 70);
```

Comment: @Gabe: I mean semi transparent.